# Dynamically re-format table

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table like this:

[image]

and want to be able dynamically to extract the contents of the first table to a format like this:

[image]

The only working method I could come up with is a nested VLOOKUP:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(L2,A1:E6,3,FALSE)),IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(L2,A1:E6,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(L2,A1:E6,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(L2,A1:E6,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(L2,A1:E6,3,FALSE))
```

I would like to be able to add/remove columns from the source table without having to redo this formula.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Can there only be one numerical value in columns 3 through 5 per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those look like structured tables and this solution uses the unique formula syntax for structured tables.

[image: Table Lookup]

The formulas in the third and fourth column of the first row of the second table are:

```
=INDEX(Table1, ROW(1:1), MATCH(1E+99, INDEX(Table1, ROW(1:1), 0)))
=INDEX(Table1[#Headers], 1, MATCH(1E+99, INDEX(Table1, ROW(1:1), 0)))
```

The formula to identify the column actually returns the column header label. This was a little confusion as to whether to return the column number or column header label due to the ambiguity of the header naming system